# In Servlet abour Servlet life cycle method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

when we override the `init(ServletConfig)` method in Servlet then we need to call `super.init(config)` but why we need to call in this situation and why need not to call when override the default `init()` method?

Answer (score 1):

```
code in GenericServlet 

 public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
      this.config = config;
      this.init();
 }

 ServletConfig intialization takes place in init(ServletConfig config)
```

If you dont call super.init(config) then the sub class init(config) method will execute
   then ServletConfig object initialization won't happen.

If you override init(),Normally the superclass init(config) will called and then subclass
   init() will called as helper method.In this case the ServltConfig object intialization 
    will happen